# ${} - Regex Expression

Tags: java, regex

I really tried to learn Regex expressions correctly, but, it really blows my mind when I need to build one of them. It`s painful and I lost several hours to build them.

So, I need the community help. I`ve an XML String, and I want to build a Regex pattern to identify any occurence of:

```
${Variable1}
${VARIABLE_TEST}
```

etc. So, anything that starts with `${` and ends with `}`.

Could anyone help-me?

Comment: Try to use regex testers. They are very useful.
http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)}").matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try with following regex:

```
\${([^}]+)}
```

Explanation:

```
\${     - starts with ${ (we have to escape special character $)
([^}]+) - match everything that is not }
}       - ending character
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/cA6zU3)

Regex with escaped `{` and `}`:

```
\$\{([^}]+)\}
```

Comment: The `{` and `}` may need escaping too.

Comment: @Biffen In this case - not really. but I will extend my solution.

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs) seems to *suggest* they do, although it's not very clear.

Comment: ...the un-escaped version gives an error (when I tried it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php)).

Comment: This will match newlines between the brackets, not sure the OP wants that, although they did say 'everything', so perhaps that's fine.  It should also use the `*` quantifier instead of `+` if `${}` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript

```js
const regex = /\${([^}]*)}/g;

const str = " Hello ${Variable1}, Well How are you ${VARIABLE  TEST} It empty ${} It's numeric ${123\$\$\$}, numeric plus $pecial char ${@123123} ${\$%!@#}";

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

In Java [Demo](https://www.online-java.com/khwy2RdJXz)

```
 final String regex = "\\$\\{([^\\}]*)\\}";
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
 while(m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
 }
```